# how to store a varibale value after page loading

Tags: asp.net

In my application there is the multiple tab concept is there. i.e i have 1st page then "next button" to move to second page, then in 2nd page 2 button(prev,next). Thus when user click prev button i need to get the fields filled in 1st page. this can be achived using state management. If is there any way except this?

Comment: You could store them in Session object. See MS documentation for an explanation of how this works: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx State management refers to maintaining state for your application during the request/response cycle and is important as HTTP is stateless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions, example of which

in your 1st page:

```
string str;
Session["someName"] = str;
```

in your 2nd page you can retrieve by calling the session, because sessoin is a GLOBAL VARIABLE,

```
string n_str;
n_str = Session["someName"] as string;
```

Comment: i can store the text box value of first page in session this much is ok, but after moving to the 2nd page when coming down again to 1st page, where to retrive the session value?(in page load i think, and it throws error because session is null)

Comment: i think you didn't got my question..no issue, my requirement is to do the multi tab . thus we can move to NEXT and PREV page.  thus my requirement is when we click prev button , the previous page fileds should be filled(the data we have entered before clicking NEXT button0

Comment: oh, so you mean you want to retain the data in the textbox, when your session is still up. Here's a link on how to use viewstate, this is the solution to your question. http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_viewstate.asp

Comment: BTW, session will not be null, unless you made a Session.Remove("someName"); or Session.RemoveAll();

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends on how your project is built, so you've many options:

1- You could build it as a single page with multiple tabs  (as HTML Divs) and the "next" and "prev" buttons show and hide these Divs, so you don't need to store the data anywhere as the page didn't change (just show and hide).

2- Store it in a global variable like "Session"
but if you've a high traffic application you may run out of memory or you'll need to use in database session instead of the default in memory session storage.

3- Save the data partially (when moving from step to step) by using a web service or from code behind to the database and then reload it again when clicking prev.

As for me I recommend the first approach as it doesn't add extra load on the servers and don't affect the performance.

Comment: as per my requiremnt the 1st one is not aplicable, the 2nd and 3rd is applicable, but storing the values in db and again retriving may make much traffic.session part i m still confuse, as when returning back to the 1st page we need to rtrive the session value in the page load and the session contain null and it throws error

Comment: You may just need to check if null and cast it to empty string or your default value. Session["name"] != null?Session["name"]:"";

Comment: default value itself is in session thus if its null how can i assign it to the fields?

Comment: Sorry but how can the session has a default value and could be null in the same time. You could send me your could we may look at it together.